# a laravel5 delete , how to pass 2 parameters to DELETE operation

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

my first idea is to send two parameters to DELETE operation!

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/sco/'.$sco->sno,$sco->cno) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">删除</button>
</form>
```

then,it is the destroy function!

```
public function destroy($sno, $cno)
{
    $query = DB::table('scos')->where('sno', $sno)->where('cno', $cno);
    $query->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('删除成功!');
}
```

but i get the result with  NotFoundHttpException

i think where problem exists is i have not passed the parameters correctly. how can i do it?
addtional information: 
'sno' means student number,
'cno' means class number,
i have to delete a specific record with the two numbers.

Comment: Seems your `url` is the problem. change it to `url('admin/sco/'.$sco->sno.'/'.$sco->cno)`

Comment: Please can you show the `Route` for this?

Comment: Can you show us the route defenition in your `routes/web.php` file?

Comment: ```
Route::post('/admin/sco/{sno}/{cno}', 'Admin\ScoController@destroy')->name('sco.delete');
```

Comment: `Route::post('/admin/sco/{sno}/{cno}', 'Admin\ScoController@destroy')->name('sco.delete');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

In **routes**:

```
Route::post('/admin/sco/{sno}/{cno}', 'Your_controller@your_action')->name('sco.delete');
```

In **views**:

```
<form action="{{ route('sno.delete', ['sno' => $sco->sno, 'cno' => $sco->cno]) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
```

Hope it help you :)

Comment: i solved the problem when i changed like this,Route::any('/admin/sco/{sno}/{cno}', 'Admin\ScoController@destroy')->name('sco.delete'); but i don't know why post does not work!!!

Comment: You can not use post as you stated `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` in the form. so only delete methods can be used.